# pong from pixle with CNN and policy gradient

Tags: python, keras, theano

i get a stuck at this point , i've readed "pong from pixel" of kapathy blog, and i wanna improve this by integrate CNN model then i've got this tutor from GG.

**link here:

https://github.com/yshvrdhn/Pong-Agent-Using-Policy-Gradients/blob/master/pong_keras.py

But i cannot run and dont know the usage of this line:
model= learning_model() ,plz someone can help me ???

***error that i got after compile these code :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\thinh dang\Desktop\pong\kerasDemo.py", line 3, in <module>
from keras.models import Sequential
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
from . import utils
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
from . import conv_utils
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\conv_utils.py", line 9, in <module>
from .. import backend as K
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\__init__.py", line 84, in <module>
from .theano_backend import *
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\keras\backend\theano_backend.py", line 7, in <module>
import theano
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano\__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
from theano.compile import (
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
from theano.compile.mode import *
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano\compile\mode.py", line 11, in <module>
import theano.gof.vm
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\vm.py", line 674, in <module>
from . import lazylinker_c
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\lazylinker_c.py", line 140, in <module>
preargs=args)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano\gof\cmodule.py", line 2388, in compile_str
(status, compile_stderr.replace('\n', '. ')))
Exception: Compilation failed (return status=1): The system cannot find the path specified.
```

Comment: Unfortunately this question is not appropriate for Stack Overflow, the only problem is that you didn't install Theano and now you don't have a C++ compiler, which Theano doesn't require but it will improve performance. Other people cannot really benefit from this question.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you don't have `theano` installed. You can do so with:

```
pip install theano
```

As a side advice, I would also recommend virtual environments, so it will be easier to keep your projects isolated.

Comment: @LucDaoDaiNhan That is not a bug, but a different problem, did you read the error message? It directly points you to the solution.

Comment: sr, i've updated my package with these instructor but its still appear like that :'(

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend working with Anaconda.

Comment: im using anaconda to installl all packgage

Comment: So why the path is: C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\theano and not: C:\anaconda2\lib\site-packages\theano or something similar?

Comment: i've install python before anaconda , cause it is make point ??

Comment: you need to change the path to where the anaconda is installed